# Increasing datetime resolution, to be used for log files

Tags: pgfplots, resolution, dateplot

I have some log files with a full time stamp like this:

```
time    value
2015-10-15 13:16:48.019901  56
2015-10-15 13:16:48.066701  53
2015-10-15 13:16:48.097900  57
2015-10-15 13:16:51.126281  61
2015-10-15 13:16:51.828276  78
2015-10-15 13:16:52.844270  101
2015-10-15 13:16:52.875470  108
2015-10-15 13:16:53.374667  104
2015-10-15 13:16:53.905063  102
2015-10-15 13:16:55.433853  103
```

I need to plot the log file using `dateplot` and `pgfplots`.
The problem is just that it can only handle up to minutes, but my log files are usually within a minute.

This works with files there are some minutes long:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xticklabel={\hour:\minute:\second\\ \day/\month\\ \year},
x tick label style={align=center}]

\addplot table [col sep=tab,trim cells=true,y=value] {
time    value
2015-10-15 13:16:48.019901  56
2015-10-15 13:16:48.066701  53
2015-10-15 13:16:48.097900  57
2015-10-15 13:16:51.126281  61
2015-10-15 13:16:51.828276  78
2015-10-15 13:16:52.844270  101
2015-10-15 13:16:52.875470  108
2015-10-15 13:16:53.374667  104
2015-10-15 13:16:53.905063  102
2015-10-15 13:16:55.433853  103
};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But files under a minute looks like this:

[image]
\

**Note:** It is important that the the whole time stamp are in the plot

Comment: Too many digits ... I am not sure if `fpu` and date&time are compatible.

Comment: Is acceptable to rotate xtick labels?

Comment: And please make your MWE compilable (include table in MWE).

Comment: Maybe you can modify http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219447/95441 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238845/95441 to fit your needs ...