# pgfplot with timestamp in microseconds

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dateplot

My example as below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.871,0)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.888,8)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.904,25)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.921,41)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.938,59)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.954,75)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.971,92)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.988,45)
(10-18-2018 16:50:28.005,62)
(10-18-2018 16:50:28.022,79)
(10-18-2018 16:50:28.039,96)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
xticklabel style= {rotate=60,anchor=north east},
xlabel=X,
ylabel=Y
]
\addplot table[ignore chars={(,)},col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously:

1. x label not correct, I wish it can be automatical match data range. I don't wish to add a min-x/max-x statement.
2. data point not distributed to the whole graph but all in the center.sounds like microsecons not being parsed!

Comment: I haven't used pgfplots in a looong time, but it looks like the date & timestamp isn't parsed properly at all.

Comment: `pgfplots` doesn't handle any smaller interval than minutes for date input. Even seconds will be ignored (set to zero), so you can't expect microseconds to work. I'd suggest calculating the microseconds elapsed from the first data point, and stating in xlabel or figure caption "Microseconds from dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS.SSS" or something.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118676/increasing-dateplots-resolution-to-seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ulrike Fischer has introduced in [this very nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445564/121799) a universal parser. (Of course, if you want to vary both the year and the milliseconds, you'll run into `dimension too large errors` but with Ulrike's nice parser you can just focus on the data you care about.) (I  also stress that *she* used the terminology `\marmottimeparseaux`, so this is one of the cases where I am not to blame for increasing the marmot awareness. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.871,0)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.888,8)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.904,25)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.921,41)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.938,59)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.954,75)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.971,92)
(10-18-2018 16:50:27.988,45)
(10-18-2018 16:50:28.005,62)
(10-18-2018 16:50:28.022,79)
(10-18-2018 16:50:28.039,96)
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xfp}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445564/121799
\def\marmottimeparseaux#1-#2-#3 #4:#5:#6xxx{\fpeval{#5* 60 + #6}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \marmot_timeparse:n { \marmottimeparseaux #1xxx }
\newcommand\TimeParse[1]{\exp_args:Nf\marmot_timeparse:n {#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
   \addplot table [,ignore chars={(,)},col sep=comma,
   x expr=\TimeParse{\thisrowno{0}},y expr=\thisrowno{1}] {data.csv};
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]