# Pgfplots: I cant include any libraries using \usepgfplotslibrary -> Dateplot not possible

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I am new here and appreciate any help given.

I am working on Windows 10 with TeXStudio and Miktex 2.9. My pgfplots Version is 1.17.
My **example code** looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        title=Inv. cum. normal,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        ]
        \addplot[blue] table{Daten_Leaking_1.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So, I am currently about to plot some graphs for my thesis, using pgfplots. I could already plot a graph and it worked fine. But most of data are weight-values with a time stamp for each. The table I want to use, for plotting the data, looks like this (with just more values):

[image: Data table I use for plotting a graph]

Its just values seperated by a tabstop. When I try to plot this table I get an Error saying:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '14:51:06' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ':51:06'.. \addplot[blue] table{Daten_Leaking_1.txt};
```

The Error appears for all rows. When I then have a look at the command:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
```

It is not marked as an error. It is just highlighted red and tells me "Command not recognized" (My TeXStudio is in German. I only translated the error. Might be a different name in English.)

[image: Thats how the code looks like after compiling]

So apparently, I can't include any libraries from pgfplots into my document. And thats the point, where I don't know what to do. Do you have any Idea, how to fix this? I am happy for any new insights.

**Things I have tried so far:**

1. Plotting the table with all time values written as decimal numbers (like 14:51:04 -> 0.61879707). It works fine and  I get a nice graph. so pgfplot itself works well.
2. Using \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.dateplot} instead. Gets me the exactly the same error and highlighting
3. I figgured out by accident, that if I misspell the library i want to add, the eroor changes to this and "\usepgfplotslibrary{dataplot}" is shown as a actual error:
4. I thought about installing pgfplots manually again. The problem is, that I do not have adminstrator rights on this PC and it would be hard to get. But from what I have seen, scrolling through the files of the installed pgfplots package, the files are pretty much the same, than the ones you get by downloading pgfplots from CTAN.

[image]

5. I tried to include other libraries. The same errors occured.

Greetings and thanks in advance, Carl

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I guess you get the error because the `dateplot` library expects *dates* (+ timestamps), but you are just stating timestamps in your data file ...

Comment: thx for the answer! But I do not think, thats the issue. Like I saw other examples where only timestamps worked just fine with dateplot. Furthermore I can't include other libraries. I think the error has something to do with the libraries, and that they can't be included.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean anything that TeXstudio highlights something as red, what really matters is whether you get get any errors when generating the PDF. There should be a panel at the bottom of TeXstudio called "Log" (or the equivalent in German), what does it say there when you try generating a PDF.  Further, the manual states that the `dateplot` library doesn't have support for seconds (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118676) , and that the date has to be included.

Comment: So the Error says this:  `I can't find file 'pgflibrarypgfplots.dataplot.code.tex'. \usepgfplotslibrary{dataplot}` and: `Emergency stop. \usepgfplotslibrary{dataplot}`                                                                                       I also tried 1. to use the same Data but add a date to the time -> didn't work, 2. to cut the seconds and only use minutes and hours + date -> didn't work either.